# MVC & JS: Using one form in a view and make it look like it's 2 views

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Before we start, I am using MVC 3, Entity Framework Model First, the web application that I am developing is suppose to let users create a evaluation card the creation is suppose to be on 2 steps.

- First step is that the user types and selects fields which is the information.
- Second step is that the users choose/select questions he/she wants for the evaluation card.

What I am trying to do is to make the first step and second step all in one form in view and use div tags to hide em with jquery. Which makes it all alot easier since I dont need use 1 view per process step. I can do these all in a single view.

Now to the problem! :)

In this View I have one submit button, this one seems to trigger my whole form even my validation that ive done with the standard jquery validation in MVC I guess it submits my post action aswell.

This is the function that I want:

When a user click on submit button I want that the validation gets approved and then hides step one and shows step two. When user clicks on the submit button after selecting questions in step two I want that the submit button triggers the post actions. I also have a extra button in phase two that can take you back to step one, which hides step two and shows step one :)

step one has div id "hiddenstep1" and step two has div id "Hiddenstep2"

Jquery script that  im trying to use for this is following which is working:

```
$("#hiddenstep1").hide();
$("#hiddenstep2).show();
```

If there is any extra information let me know and I will edit my question.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

So you want something like a wizard?

There are several jQuery plugins for Wizards that support validaton.

Stepy is a good one:

http://www.wbotelhos.com/stepy/

It doesn't use a submit button until the final step of the form. With some minor hacking you could support server side validation and kick people back to the step that had an error with something like this:

```
            var firstError = $('.input-validation-error:first,span.field-validation-error');
            if (firstError.length != 0) {
                $('#dealWizard').stepy('step', $(firstError).closest('fieldset').index() + 1);
            }
```

With Stepy, each one of your steps are contained in a fieldset and all field sets are contained within the same form.

Example:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

        <fieldset title="Step 1">
            <legend>Choose Something</legend>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Field1)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Field1)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Field1)
            </div>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset title="Step 2">
            <legend>Choose Something Else</legend>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Field2)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Field2)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Field2)
            </div>
        </fieldset>
        <input type="submit" class="finish"/>

}
```

Comment: dont you have to give form a class or id?

Comment: When I use the plugin I always give the form an ID so I can call $('#formID').stepy(); on it but you could also use $('form').stepy(); if you needed.